# Problemas con json al buscar datos con php y ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

Estimados tengo un un ajax que me trae datos desde la base de datos con php a una tabla el codigo es el siguiente

Ajax:

```
$('#selplan').change(function(){
    var idplan = $('#selplan').val();

    var consulta = $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        url: '../Model/buscarplan.php',
        data: {plan: idplan},
        dataType: 'JSON'
    });


    consulta.done(function (data) {
        if ( data &&  data.error !== undefined) {
            $('#estado').html('Ha ocurrido un error: ' + data.error);
            return false;
        } else {
            if (data.Minutos !== undefined) {
                $('#datosplan #txtMinutos').val(data.Minutos);
            }
            if (data.Datos !== undefined) {
                $('#datosplan #txtDatos').val(data.Datos);
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
    consulta.fail(function () {
        $('#estado').html('Ha habido un error contactando el servidor.');
        return false;
    });

})
```

mi php:

```
<?php namespace Model;

$conexion = new \mysqli("localhost", "", md5(''), "");

if ($conexion->connect_error) {
    echo "Fallo al conectar:".$conexion->connect_error() or die();
}

if (! empty($_POST['plan'])) {

    $idplan = $_POST['plan'];
    $query = "SELECT IdPlan,Nombre,Minutos,Datos FROM plan WHERE IdPlan = $idplan";
    $result = $conexion->query($query);
    die(json_encode($result->fetch_array()));
}

$conexion->close();
```

antes tenia dos registro en esa tabla  y me los busca bien y me carga los datos pero le agrege un tercer registro y ese en especial no me trae los datos me devuelve null, alguna sugerencia? aca pego el error

> Validate.js:96 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Minutos' of
>   null
>       at Object. (Validate.js:96)
>       at i (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at A (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: Hola Pablo, ¿probaste  ejecutar la consulta sola en la base de datos y ver si te devuelve los 3 registros?

Comment: Tu PHP no está controlado absolutamente. Deberías controlar su flujo, creando siempre un objeto (array), también cuando haya errores, y responder ese array. Luego en el `done` evalúas primero si en la respuesta hay algún `data.error` sencillamente. Una de las posibilidades no contempladas en tu código es que la consulta no devuelva nada. Otro problema del código es el enorme agujero de seguridad que tienes al no usar consultas preparadas.

Comment: Una recomendación. Para mejorar tu base de datos y brindarle mayor "portabilidad" tanto nombre de tablas como nombre de campos deben in er minúsculas y además el nombre de la tabla puede ser plural mientras que el nombre de los campos es en singular. Tomado de traducción al español de la documentación oficial de MySQL. Link aquí: http://web.archive.org/web/20140804153005/http://dev.mysql.com:80/doc/refman/5.0/es/name-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: @LucasAccastello hola si lo intente y me devuelve los tres registros!

Comment: hola @A.Cedano gracias por la observacion, lo mejorare, saludos

Comment: Hola @Huskie gracias por la observacion y la documentacion, lo voy a leer gracias por el aporte

Comment: De nada. Revisa con un var_dump($result) después de $result = $conexion->query($query); quizás el 3er registro este trayendo vacio el campo Minutos. Revisa y me avisas